# Lazy Sorting HackerRank Python

Tags: python-3.x

I am new to coding and so the following code I wrote may be incorrect or sub-optimal. However, the problem I have is that I do not understand the input and thus cannot get the code to run (I only tested it with custom inputs).

The essence of the problem is that you have some sequence of numbers and you want to arrange the sequence monotonically (nondecreasing or nonincreasing). You do this by a random shuffle. How many shuffles does it take for you to get to the monotonic sequence via a random shuffle? You can find the problem [here](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/lazy-sorting/problem) and here is my code below:

```
#!/bin/python3 ------ The following import is given in the prompt

import os
import sys

# Complete the solve function below. Here is my code below
def solve(P):
    P.sort()
    correct = P
    count = []
    i = 0
    # Here I am trying to calculate the number of ways to get the desired monotonic sequence
    # I count the number of repeated numbers in the sequence as separate items in a list
    for j in range(i,len(correct)):
        if correct[i] != correct[j] or i == len(correct) - 1:
            count.append(j-i)
            i = j
            j = len(correct)
        else:
            j = j + 1
    summ = 0
    for k in range(len(count)):
        summ = summ + count[k]
    if summ == len(correct):
        i = len(correct)
    poss = [1]*len(count)
    for k in range(len(count)):
        for l in range(1,count[k]+1):
            poss[k] = poss[k]*l
    possible = 1
    for x in poss:
        possible = possible * x
    # This is calculating the number of different permutations of n distinct elements
    total = 1
    n = len(correct)
    for i in range(1,n+1):
        total = total * i
    # Calculating the probability to the 6th decimal place
    probability = float(possible / total)
    expected = round(1/probability, 6)
    print(expected)


# The following code is given in the prompt to input the test cases

if __name__ == '__main__':
    fptr = open(os.environ['OUTPUT_PATH'], 'w')

    P_count = int(input())

    P = list(map(int, input().rstrip().split()))

    result = solve(P)

    fptr.write(str(result) + '\n')

    fptr.close()
```

In my code, I just assumed that P is the sequence of numbers you receive from the input.

Comment: from the if __name__ == '__main__' block it does look like it will pass a list of ints. Are you sure that is what is going wrong?

Comment: Thanks for your response! The code runs without any errors but there is no output. I have tried print(P) and print(P_count) and there is no output either. Yes, I believe P is a list of ints (I believe it's supposed to represent the sequence).